# I'm trying to loop over a XMLSlurper find statement using a list array. Can you do this?

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I'm trying to loop over an expression like this changing the string 'question-hyperlink' to
an item in a list I'm new to groovy and can't find a way that works. Do you really have to hard code this ? Every example I can find is hardcoded

```
.find{ it.@class == 'question-hyperlink'}it.book.title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to be hardcoded, you can use a list and you can use the `in` operator:

```
xml = '''<div>
    <div class="header">header div</div>
    <div class="body">body div</div>
    <span class="footer">footer span</span>
</div>
'''

node = new XmlSlurper().parseText xml

// the element's classes we want
classes = ['header', 'body']

contents = node.breadthFirst().findAll { it.@class in classes }*.text()

assert contents == ['header div', 'body div']
```